# No internet access on docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, internet-connection

I've just installed docker on a virtual machine and created a ubuntu container. When I run "apt update" I get the following errors.

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done        
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I already tried to enable the DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker to use Google's DNS and restarted docker, but it didn't work.

I also tried this:

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
docker -d
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Exactly what changes did you make to `DOCKER_OPTS`?  How did you verify that your changes were active?  Verify using `ps` that the Docker daemon is running with the options you configured, and look at `/etc/resolv.conf` inside your container and see if the `nameserver` setting is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Already solved it. What I had to do was comment out the

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

entry located in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.